# errorplacement not allowing jquery validate to work

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate, errorplacement

This is my first time using javascript in a website. I have very low understanding of the language and rely very much on tutorials and reading through other people's questions/solutions.

I have a HTML form that I formatted using a table format. I happen to have some radio buttons in the form too and what happens is once I include `errorPlacement` in the javascript code, validation for the form doesn't happen. I need for the error message not to disrupt the text of my radio buttons, hopefully appearing on top before the options or after.

If I take out the `errorPlacement` codes, validation ('this field is required' messages appear at the default location) works as per normal.

Please have a look at my code and let me know if I'm missing anything. I have a feeling it's something simple like a comma or bracket and I have tried a few workarounds but nothing seemed to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#quoteform").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.insertBefore(element);   
             },          
        }),
    })                        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had a few syntax errors - should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#quoteform").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi Politus... Yes that seems right. The validation is working. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

error is a string. So `error.insertBefore` doesn't make sense. 
Try `$("<div>").insertBefore (element).text (error)`

Comment: no, error is a jQuery wrapped set containing just one element which is the error - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Hi politus, I'm sorry but I don't really understand your explanation. Does this mean that I shouldn't use element for error placement?

Comment: no, you should use it, I am just saying this answer is incorrect - in errorPlacement the two arguments are both jQuery objects so error.insertBefore(element) is fine

Comment: alright.. thanks. i thought so too... I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong with the script.